# Storing global data with socket.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, socket.io

I'm trying to store all user's data in an array with socket.io, but when i put a new information, the last one is deleted.

```js
var userInformations = <{}[]>[];

socketInfo.on('putUserInformations', (userData:{}) => {
        userInformations.push(userData)
        console.log(userInformations)
    })
```

Comment: Is the server process maybe shutting down (e.g. reloading) in-between? Variables wouldn't persist between reloads.

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you want to store something about what the user is doing in a particular room? There are two ways to do this, either store it on the socket ID, or store it in the room.

The way I've done this before is as follows. For storing data about the room, I attach it to the room ID by adding new keys to the room object. While the room remains active, this data will remain actively attached to the room, so you can easily access it through your code

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms[ROOM_ID_GOES_HERE].lockedInput = { "some_data" : 1 }
```

I'm not sure how you've done this but you can test out this stuff by console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms) to see what you have there. For storing information about the socket user, you can just attach this directly to the socket, i.e.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) { 

   socket.user = 'User 1';

});
```

One is private to that particular socket, and one is private to a particular room. Both of these allow you to gather information on the room/user and it will persist while the socket is active. When the socket/room are both closed, the data will not persist, but you can store it in a database and pull it in when the user reconnects if you need to.

Comment: but, the user's informations comes from front-end through socket,  and i want to put it in a back-end array, i not want to stores this information in room or user's socket, understand ?

Comment: Yeah so just post the data to the backend like you would normally, and then store it on the socket. The socket is associated with that one user. If you want everyone to have access to that data, then store the data on the room using the socket IDs as unique user identifiers, or you can use emails or usernames if it's linked up to an authentication system.